# String contains \n and it leads to an ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Actual code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/")

two_str = "string_one\nstring_two"
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('code').value = '%s';" % two_str)
```

## Here is the error itself:

[image]
As you can see, variable two_str contains "\n" (new line separator). And its presence leads to an error. But if its removed - everything works perfectly.

## How to solve this problem?

P.S.
I need to have a string with "\n" new line separator.

Comment: try escaping the escape character `"string_one\\nstring_two"`

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '\\n' to start a new line in a string. The first \ tells Python to read the second \ as part of the string.

```
string = "\\n"
print string

returns "\n"
```

Comment: It's called escaping... see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 1):

use raw strings so the backslash doesn't get used as an escape char.

so change:

```
two_str = "string_one\nstring_two"
```

to

```
two_str = r"string_one\nstring_two"
```

Comment: And how to use string as raw when string object is shown as variable in code ?

Comment: This is good practice for copying file paths. I use it for ArcPy scripting